# Load Multiple images (BLOBs) into the Oracle Database

Tags: import, oracle-12c

I have a folder with several images. My database table is a simple table with 2 fields: name (char) and image (BLOB). How can I import my images located in my C disk (e.g.: C:\Users\me\images) into my table?

Note: By using the SQL Developer I found a way to import 1 image per time, but I am looking for a solution that could import my entire folder; and when I am choosing import data from sql developer, I am getting the following error:

> There are no readers registered to the jpg type.